# Distribution of Expectation function into a $|X-Y|$

Tags: random-variables, expectation

We know that $E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$. But why is $E|X-Y|$ $\ne$ $E|X| - E|Y|?$

Comment: $|X-Y| \geq |X|-|Y|$. You can follow the definition of expectation to prove the result.

Comment: @XianjinYang  Thank you.

Comment: For a simple counterexample, consider $Y=-X$ with $\mathbb E[X]\ne0$. Then $|X-Y|=2|X|$ so $$\mathbb E[|X-Y|]=2\mathbb E[|X|]>0$$ but $$\mathbb E[|X|]-\mathbb E[|Y|]=\mathbb E[|X|]-\mathbb E[|X|]=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $X \ge Y$, then

$$E|X-Y| = EX - EY$$

Otherwise

$$E|X-Y| = EY - EX$$

Neither of which are necessarily equal to $$E|X| - E|Y|$$

Comment: "If $X \ge Y$, then $E|X-Y| = EX - EY$ Otherwise $E|X-Y| = EY - EX$" This is wrong.

Comment: Somebody upvoted a post stating that E|X-Y| is either EX-EY or EY-EX. Fascinating.